# Adding a root certification authority to a java application

Tags: centos, fedora, java, ssl, certificates

I've installed Jenkins on CentOS7 and I was getting an SSL error when trying to update/install plugins. After some investigation, it turned out I had a missing root CA certificate in the Java CA store.

I used the `keytool` utility to add the missing CA certificate into the Java CA store and it worked. However I find it annoying to have to tamper with that.

Isn't there a way to make Java inherit the root CA certificates trusted by the system? If yes, how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply copy your certificate files to this directory on CentOS 7.x:

```
$ sudo cp <cert file> /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
```

Once the certificate files put into this directory, run this command to update the system with this newly added certificate:

```
$ sudo update-ca-trust
```

#### What about Java

If you look through the man page for `update-ca-trust` you'll see the following section:

> $ man update-ca-trust
>
> ...
>
> */etc/pki/java/cacerts*
>
> Classic filename, file contains a list of CA certificates trusted 
>      for TLS server authentication usage, in the Java keystore file 
>      format, without distrust information. This file is a
>      symbolic link that refers to the consolidated output created by the 
>      update-ca-trust command.

If you look at that file you can see how it plugs into the rest of the `/etc/pki` directory structure:

```
$ ll /etc/pki/java/cacerts
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 40 May  2 10:41 /etc/pki/java/cacerts -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts
```

And if we run the Java `keytool` against it:

```
$ keytool -list -keystore /etc/pki/java/cacerts -storepass changeit |& head
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 155 entries

hellenicacademicandresearchinstitutionsrootca2011, May 2, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): FE:45:65:9B:79:03:5B:98:A1:61:B5:51:2E:AC:DA:58:09:48:22:4D
taiwangrca, May 2, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): F4:8B:11:BF:DE:AB:BE:94:54:20:71:E6:41:DE:6B:BE:88:2B:40:B9
teliasonerarootcav1, May 2, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
```

You can see that the above has picked up all the certificates available and they're incorporated automatically into this Java JKS file. This file is available to any Java application that's running on the system.

#### References

- [How to add Certificate Authority in centos7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043442/how-to-add-certificate-authority-in-centos7)
- [How to reset the list of trusted CA certificates in RHEL 6 & RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549003)